# CRUD - I can't insert data using express and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to insert a category in the database following the instructions of a course I am taking and I am unable to insert it with the create method. It shows ... loading in Postman and nothing happens and no error message appears on the console. Here are my files.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser') 
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const expressValidator = require('express-validator')  
require('dotenv').config()
//import routes
const authRoutes =  require('./routes/auth')
const userRoutes =  require('./routes/user')
const categoryRoutes =  require('./routes/category')

// app
const app = express()

// db
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
})
.then(() => console.log('DB Connected'))

// middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(expressValidator())

// routes middleware
app.use('/api', authRoutes)
app.use('/api', userRoutes)
app.use('/api', categoryRoutes)

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

**routes/category.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const { create } = require('../controllers/category')
const { requireSignin} = require('../controllers/category')
const { userById } = require('../controllers/user')

router.post('/category/create/:userId', function(req, res){
  requireSignin, 
  create
});

router.param("userId", userById)

module.exports = router
```

**controllers/category.js**

```
const Category = require("../models/category")
const { errorHandler } = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler")

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const category = new Category(req.body)
  category.save((err, data) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: errorHandler(err)
      })
    }
    res.json({ data })
  })
}
```

**models/category.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema)
```

Comment: What the value of process.env.DATABASE? and are u sure the mongodb server in up?

Comment: is "DB Connected" printed in the console?

Comment: Yes DB Connected is printed in the console

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure that data is actually being returned, your create function needs to be asynchronous. Adding async/await to the save function should confirm that you are properly saving the data to the database before returning.

Comment: go to mongoosejs.com and see the example. mongoose support callback as well

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have an error in your route setup. I assume `requireSignin` and `create` should be middleware functions.

So instead of

```js
router.post('/category/create/:userId', function(req, res){
  requireSignin, 
  create
});
```

you should try this

```js
router.post('/category/create/:userId', requireSignin, create);
// assuming 'create' is the last one, since you are ending the request there
// also assuming that 'requireSignin' is setup as middleware, calling next function
```

Comment: I made the suggested changes, but an error message now appears: 
UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found

Comment: I guess in your `requireSignin` middleware you are checking for a token right ? Did you include the token in your request ?

Comment: I suggest leaving out the `requiredSignin` middleware for now to test if the rest is working. There might be another error in there (you didn't include it in your question so I can't tell).

Comment: Yes! When I hide this Require Signing function, an error message appears: "error": "Path` name` is required. " but I did the postman injection correctly: {
"name": "JavaScript"
}

Comment: Can you include the postman request you are performing in your question ? Also try logging `req.body` in you `create` function before creating the new mongoose document.

Comment: I will read the course code more carefully, to see if I made a mistake. If the errors continue, I will return here.

Comment: Hey @claudiobitar ! I wonder if you were able to solve your problem ?